# If $f_1, f_2, \dots$ are Riemann integrable and $\sum_n \int |f_n| < \infty$ is $f=\sum_n f_n$ Riemann Integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

> If $f_1, f_2, \dots$ are Riemann integrable and $\sum_n \int |f_n| < \infty$ is $f=\sum_n f_n$ Riemann Integrable?

I believe the answer is no, because isn't this sort of scenario the motivation for introducing the Lebesgue integral. I am having trouble synthesizing a counter-example.

Comment: If you consider $f_n(x)=x$ for all $n$, then $\sum \int_{-a}^a f_n = 0$ but $f$ doesn't exist.

Comment: @Josué Tonelli-Cueto Ok, thanks, I see where I made an error. I delete my answer

Comment: @Kelenner Your answer is easily corrected...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $[a,b]\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ be a an interval and let $\{r_1,r_2,r_3,...\}$ be an enumeration of the rational numbers in the set $\mathbb{Q}\cap[a,b]$. Define
$$f_n(x):=\chi_n(x)= \begin{cases} 
      1 & x=r_n \\
      0 & \text{else} 
   \end{cases}
$$
Clearly for each $n$ we have $f_n$ is Riemann integrable with Riemann integral $\int_a^bf_n(x)\,dx=0$. Morevoer $$\sum_n\int_a^b|f_n(x)|dx=\sum_n\int_a^bf_n(x)dx=\sum_n 0=0<+\infty$$ 
But $f(x):=\sum_nf_n(x)$ (pointwise) is the following function
$$f(x):=\sum_n\chi_n(x)= \begin{cases} 
      1 & x\in\mathbb{Q}\cap[a,b]\\
      0 & \text{else} 
   \end{cases}$$
which is not Riemann integrable.